# Mapping over vectors of different lengths? - R

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have a csv file of forest fires.

Data: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/forest-fires/

[image]

I'm trying to create box plots for each variable with the x-axis being month/day.

I don't understand why listing the variables out doesn't work but referencing the dataframe by index works.

```
createBox <- function(x, y) {
  ggplot(data = forestFires) +
    aes_string(x = x, y = y) +
    geom_boxplot()
}

# code below doesn't work
# Error: Mapped vectors must have consistent lengths:
# * `.x` has length 12
# * `.y` has length 8

x_var_month <- c("jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun", "jul", "aug", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec")
x_var_day <- c("sun","mon","tue","wed","thu","fri","sat")
y_var <- c("FFMC", "DMC", "DC", "ISI", "temp", "RH", "wind", "rain")

# code below works

x_var_month <- names(forestFires)[3]
x_var_day <- names(forestFires)[4]
y_var <- names(forestFires)[5:12]

monthBox <- map2(x_var_month, y_var, createBox)
dayBox <- map2(x_var_day, y_var, createBox)

monthBox
dayBox
```

I don't think I need to fix my code. I'm just trying to understand it.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] of your data with `dput` so we can try to reproduce your issues

Comment: In the first instance you gave a vector of character values, in the second you gave `x_var_month` (and `y_var_day`) a single value which was used as the column name to access those values. (The values given to `y_var` were the same in both instances.)